# How to cut all tabulations and whitespaces Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a `.sh` file:

```
test -e "$APP_SERVER_HOME"

if [ $? != 0 ]; then

   echo "Application server home $APP_SERVER_HOME does not exist"

   exit 6

fi
```

How to cut all whitespaces and tabulations from `APP_SERVER_HOME` variable before test command?

Comment: Can you provide an example? There is whitespace, which isn't part of the path? How did it get there?

Comment: APP_SERVER_HOME for example equals "   D:/helloword    "

Comment: You should remove the space where it came from. Else you will have to fix it over and over again.

Comment: Why not: if ! test -e "$APP_SERVER_HOME"; then ... fi.  No need to explicitly check $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
APP_SERVER_HOME=`echo "$APP_SERVER_HOME" |sed 's/\s//g'`
```

Is this what you want?

Note: If it contained " C:\Program Files\Foo\bar.exe " it will now contain "C:\ProgramFiles\Foo\bar.exe" which is probably not what you want.

```
APP_SERVER_HOME=`echo "$APP_SERVER_HOME" |sed 's/^\s\+//' |sed 's/\s\+$//'`
```

This one will just trim the leading and trailing whitespace, not internal spaces.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see the update, though, for a version that may suit your needs even better.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using shell parameter expansion approach ([described here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

```
shopt -s extglob

${APP_SERVER_HOME##+([[:blank:]])}
```

Comment: 1) you need `%%` to remove from the end of the string; 2) for spaces *and* tabs, use `+([[:space:]])`; 3) the "extglob" shell option needs to be set (`shopt -s extglob`)

Comment: " D:/helloword " doesn't look very bashy, does it. :)

Comment: @glenn jackman: thank you for your corrections; my fault - posted it blindly, wanted to through an idea

Comment: @glenn jackman: think that [[:blank:]] is better - covers spaces and tabs

Comment: @glenn: I did so. Now I'm confused. :)